# How to dynamically choose the derived column transformation based on the given flat file

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-express

I need to get data from flat files to DB using `SSIS`. The problem here is, I have to dynamically choose the Derived Column Transformation(**DCT**) depending on the flat file.

**Example:**

Suppose I have `flatfile-1` which need the DCT with 5 columns,
then if I get another `flatfile-2` which needs DCT with 10 columns. So how can I dynamically choose the DCT basing on the flat files?

I have to do it for many tables ... kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got a way to do this,
I am writing a C# code for generating the SSIS package. So for each flat file I get in a loop I will process it basing on the number (Each file belongs to a table which is indicated by a number.) Now when I get the flat file I am extracting its name (which contains the number) then on the fly I am getting the table name and the columns of this data group by querying on meta table and use the obtained columns as the columns for "Derived Column Transformation" and basing on the positions (this is in my case where the flat file import is done basing on their positions.) I think by generating the package pro-grammatically we will be able to generate packages for each flat file.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer You were probably not hoping to hear: unfortunately, You can't do that. SSIS packages require constant metadata which means that all external metadata (source and destination tables) in the dataflow should not change. You can take it this way: SSIS considers changes in metadata as possible error.

Maybe You should consider [BIDSHelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Biml%20Package%20Generator) and utilize its BIML functionalities.